# Should pet health insurance questions be tagged under the health-insurance tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should *pet* health insurance questions be tagged under the <kbd>[health-insurance](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-insurance)</kbd> tag?

Either that or a new tag for health insurance questions about pets?

Not necessarily a difficult question or big enough distinction but legally speaking I'd wager there are quite a few differences.

Answer (score 3):

From a legal (regulatory) POV, I believe that pet health insurance is essentially unrelated to human health insurance, and is similar only in being a contract thing. Classifying it with human health insurance would be misleading, IMO.

Comment: +1 -- they should be tagged as [tag:contract] and/or [tag:insurance] questions.

Comment: Should there be a follow-up question on whether there ought to be a new tag just for it? It seems to be more concisely dubbed `pet-insurance` over `pet-health-insurance`.